# XSL For Each Unique Value Do

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, unique

I am new to XSL and working with a very large and complex database and I am stumped on something.

*While I cannot discuss all the details or share the specifics of the XML, I can tell you that it is a breakdown of a complex system made up of other complex systems made up of raw materials. There are numerous layers of information.*

In this case, I need to extract a description of one of the specific type of subcomponents of a subassembly in a system. It is possible, and typical, for these subcomponents to be used multiple times in a subassembly, and subassemblies can also be used multiple times in a system.

In this case, if a duplicate occurs, I need to ignore it. Additionally, if a unique value exists, but occurs in the wrong place, it also needs to be ignored.

When such an item is found, I am extracting its description. (Note that while I am extracting descriptions, I am not concerned with the description being unique, only the item with which it is associated.)

I'm using the following code (see XSL below) to drill down to some of the most basic subassemblies, ignoring items that occur in the wrong processes, with no problems aside from duplicates which occur in the correct process and meet the other requirements.

As you will see, I am setting the value of a variable which is called later to be displayed in a table cell. This process is also working well.

I just need to know how to modify this code to filter out duplicates.

I have tried several `<xsl:key>` and `preceding` approaches, including several variations of ***Meunchian Groupings***, but none have worked thus far. (To be fair, I am not 100% certain I have entered them correctly, though I feel I did.) In some cases such formulas return no result (They cause a blank cell in the table.) and in others they appear to wipe out the block of code below them. (Or, they make an infinitely large blank cell that fills the remainder of the page.)

***Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!***

**XML**

```
<design>
    <operation>
    <operation uom="" trantag="operation">10</operation>
        <layer>
            <layerno>10</layerno>
            <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
            <bom>
                <position>10</position>
                <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
            </bom>
            <bom>
                <position>20</position>
                <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X1</bomitem>
                <description>DESCRIPTION_X1</description>
            </bom>
        </layer>
    </operation>
    <subdesign>
        <design>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">10</operation>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>10</layerno>
                        <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X2</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X2</description>
                        </bom>
                        <bom>
                            <position>20</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X3</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X3</description>
                        </bom>
                        <bom>
                            <position>30</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>20</layerno>
                        <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X4</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X4</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">20</operation>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>10</layerno>
                        <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X3</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X3</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>20</layerno>
                        <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X5</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X5</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
            </operation>
        </design>
        <design>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">10</operation>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>10</layerno>
                        <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X2</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X2</description>
                        </bom>
                        <bom>
                            <position>20</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X6</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X6</description>
                        </bom>
                        <bom>
                            <position>30</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>20</layerno>
                        <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X7</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X7</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">20</operation>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>10</layerno>
                        <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>20</layerno>
                        <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X5</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X5</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">30</operation>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>10</layerno>
                        <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM2</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_I2</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>20</layerno>
                        <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X8</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X8</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">40</operation>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>10</layerno>
                        <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
                    <layer>
                        <layerno>20</layerno>
                        <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                        <bom>
                            <position>10</position>
                            <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X1</bomitem>
                            <description>DESCRIPTION_X1</description>
                        </bom>
                    </layer>
            </operation>
        </design>
    </subdesign>
</design>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:oldxsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:local="#local-functions">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>

<xsl:variable name="result">

    <xsl:for-each select="/design/subdesign/design/operation/layer[process = 'SINGLES']">

        <xsl:variable name="test" select="bom/bomitem"/>
            <xsl:if test="starts-with($test,'ITEM')">
                <xsl:variable name="print" select="bom/description"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$print"/><xsl:text><![CDATA[<br />]]></xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:variable>

<table style="width:4.0in; border:0; table-layout: fixed">

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;">
            Result :
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will, incorrectly, output:

```
Result:        DESCRIPTION_I1
               DESCRIPTION_I2
               DESCRIPTION_I1
```

***The desired result would be:***

```
Result:        DESCRIPTION_I1
               DESCRIPTION_I2
```

Thanks.

***I am using XLST 1.0.***

Comment: If this is a "must," then it will take time.

This is a very, very, very large and complex database filled with proprietary information using a very, very long XSL stylesheet to sort through it all...

Surely there is a way to determine the issue without this?

Comment: @Simcik Just make up a simple example that demonstrates the problem (the simpler, the better). Otherwise we have no idea what your code relates to. Please also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Elimination of duplicates, or grouping, in XSLT 1.0 requires the rather non-intuitive coding pattern known as Muenchian Grouping. You need to study it. I don't know whether that's what you were doing when you said you tried using keys: but if you tried something and it didn't work the only way we can help you is if you tell us exactly what you tried and exactly how it failed.

Comment: The XML you have added is not well-formed, and the XSLT is incomplete. Learn about Muenchian grouping here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I have made a stripped-down version of the XML I'm working with and posted it above. I've also updated the XSL to account for this. The coding above produces the results noted at the bottom of the page. Thanks for the help and sorry for the lack of specific information upfront. I was hoping I was just missing something simple...

Comment: As I noted, I have tried several variations of Muenchian Grouping, but none have been successful. (See OP for more information.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions thus far. Hopefully the improved XML/XSL above will lead to even better results. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant to post this here sooner, but got sidetracked. Here was the solution that worked for me:

As suggested by Daniel, and as determined through trail and error, the `xsl:key` cannot be contained within `HTML` tags (as I was originally trying to do) nor can it be declared inside the `xsl:template` tags.

By moving the `xsl:key` to the very beginning of the stylesheet, using it to help determine the value of an `xsl:variable`, and then calling that value later in an `HTML` section, I was able to achieve the desired results.

While this did require me to rewrite nearly the entire stylesheet, it works as it should and the final result is better organized and more expandable in the future.

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:oldxsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:local="#local-functions"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">

<!-- KEYS -->

    <xsl:key name="desc" match="/design/subdesign/design/operation/layer[process = 'SINGLES']/bom[starts-with(bomitem,'ITEM')]" use="description"/>

<!-- XSL & VARIABLES -->

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:for-each select="/design/subdesign/design/operation/layer[process = 'SINGLES']/bom[starts-with(bomitem,'ITEM')][count(. | key('desc', description)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

<!-- HTML -->

<html>

    <table style="width:4.0in; border:0; table-layout: fixed">

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;">
                Result :
            </td>
            <td colspan="5">
                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output:**

```
<html>
    <table style="width:4.0in; border:0; table-layout: fixed">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;"> Result : </td>
            <td colspan="5">DESCRIPTION_I1<br>DESCRIPTION_I2<br></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html
```

*Thanks again, Daniel!*

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your sample XSLT and was able to get the correct results. Hopefully you will be able to adapt it to your actual code. (I'm not very good at Muenchian grouping; I normally use `xsl:for-each-group` in 2.0.)

**XML Input**

```
<design>
    <operation>
        <operation uom="" trantag="operation">10</operation>
        <layer>
            <layerno>10</layerno>
            <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
            <bom>
                <position>10</position>
                <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
            </bom>
            <bom>
                <position>20</position>
                <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X1</bomitem>
                <description>DESCRIPTION_X1</description>
            </bom>
        </layer>
    </operation>
    <subdesign>
        <design>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">10</operation>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>10</layerno>
                    <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X2</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X2</description>
                    </bom>
                    <bom>
                        <position>20</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X3</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X3</description>
                    </bom>
                    <bom>
                        <position>30</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>20</layerno>
                    <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X4</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X4</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">20</operation>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>10</layerno>
                    <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X3</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X3</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>20</layerno>
                    <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X5</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X5</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
            </operation>
        </design>
        <design>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">10</operation>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>10</layerno>
                    <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X2</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X2</description>
                    </bom>
                    <bom>
                        <position>20</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X6</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X6</description>
                    </bom>
                    <bom>
                        <position>30</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>20</layerno>
                    <process trntag="NOT_SINGLES">NOT_SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X7</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X7</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">20</operation>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>10</layerno>
                    <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>20</layerno>
                    <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X5</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X5</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">30</operation>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>10</layerno>
                    <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM2</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_I2</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>20</layerno>
                    <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X8</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X8</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
            </operation>
            <operation>
                <operation uom="" trantag="operation">40</operation>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>10</layerno>
                    <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">ITEM1</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_I1</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
                <layer>
                    <layerno>20</layerno>
                    <process trntag="SINGLES">SINGLES</process>
                    <bom>
                        <position>10</position>
                        <bomitem uom="" trantag="item">X1</bomitem>
                        <description>DESCRIPTION_X1</description>
                    </bom>
                </layer>
            </operation>
        </design>
    </subdesign>
</design>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="desc" match="/design/subdesign/design/operation/layer[process = 'SINGLES']/bom[starts-with(bomitem,'ITEM')]" use="description"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <table style="width:4.0in; border:0; table-layout: fixed">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;"> Result : </td>
          <td colspan="5">
            <xsl:for-each select="/design/subdesign/design/operation/layer[process = 'SINGLES']/bom[starts-with(bomitem,'ITEM')][count(. | key('desc', description)[1]) = 1]">
              <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
              <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```html
<html>
   <table style="width:4.0in; border:0; table-layout: fixed">
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;"> Result : </td>
         <td colspan="5">DESCRIPTION_I1<br>DESCRIPTION_I2<br></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html
```

---

**Edit**

Example of using an `xsl:variable`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="desc" match="/design/subdesign/design/operation/layer[process = 'SINGLES']/bom[starts-with(bomitem,'ITEM')]" use="description"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="results">
      <xsl:for-each select="/design/subdesign/design/operation/layer[process = 'SINGLES']/bom[starts-with(bomitem,'ITEM')][count(. | key('desc', description)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        <br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <html>
      <table style="width:4.0in; border:0; table-layout: fixed">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="vertical-align: top;"> Result : </td>
          <td colspan="5">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$results"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Daniel - Thanks, but this is still not working. I cannot combine the table information with the variable testing as you have done due to the way in which the output is formatted. (The HTML output you have above IS correct, but this must be combined with other components [not shown here] which for the entire table. That table is then placed into an even larger table.)

I tried to take what you have suggested and alter it so that the table information is not included, but it is not working. See the code below:

Comment: @Simcik - I've added an example of using an `xsl:variable`. Hopefully this helps. (You can move the variable to be a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet` if you want. Would be cleaner that way imo.)

Comment: Well, I understand what you've done, and I think it COULD work, but it would require a LOT of modification to the stylesheet...

It seems that the `xsl:key` must be declared outside of the the `xsl:template`, that's doable at least. The second issue seems to be much larger... It seems the code you've posted only works OUTSIDE of the `html` tags. If that's the case, I will need to do even more work to make this solution compatible. Is there a way to do what you've done INSIDE of `html` tags?

Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: I was able to successfully implement this code OUTSIDE of the `html` brackets. I feel I can make this approach work, but it will require significantly more work. Is there a way to do this that will work within the `html` tags? 

Thank you for the help!